# How could I match a word with pipe symbol in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string variable:

var sTest = "OOR|the OOR me|this is test|OOR|OOR this is me";

How can I use the match function to search out total of count for word "OOR|"?

When I use the following code, it will return me  4 as the result
var count = (sTest.match(/OOR/g) || []).length;

and it will throw error when I using the following code:
var count = (sTest.match(/OOR|/g) || []).length;

Does anyone know how could I solve this issue?
I expected the return result is 2.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` has meaning for regular expressions, so if you want to match it as a string you have to escape it like this:

```
(sTest.match(/OOR\|/g) || []).length;
```

Then you will get the desired result.

As an aside, `|` is just "or". Meaning `/abc|xyz/g` will match "abc" and "xyz"

Comment: ...and, relevantly, `/OOR|/` is "`OOR` or nothing", which trivially matches everywhere (as you can find an empty substring between each character, as well as at both ends). The only place it won't match is before and inside `OOR`, as regexp won't let you find overlapping matches, and `OOR` is listed before the empty string alternative.